# Create Function - PIPELINED DB2

Tags: db2, stored-functions

Does someone know how I can create that query below on DB2 database?

```
FUNCTION GPRS7001(
    pe_sTexto       VARCHAR2,
    pe_sDelimitador VARCHAR2)
RETURN v_ttTabela PIPELINED;
```

I don't how I create PIPELINED table on DB2 database.

I tried to execute this:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GPRS7001( pe_sTexto VARCHAR(300))
    RETURNS TABLE( pe_sTexto VARCHAR(300)
                   ,pe_sDelimitador VARCHAR(300)
                 )
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    RETURNS -- WTF ;
```

Db2 version 10.5

Answer (score 0):

If you properly configure your Db2 database for Oracle-emulation, then Db2 may run a pipelined function without changes.

Refer to the documentation on V10.5 Knowledge Center for details of PL/SQL support, PL/SQL pipelined functions, and the PIPE statement.

Comment: Mao   ive tried differents ways to execute it , but didnt work.  I already  read compatibility doc ( Oracle to DB2 ) , but all of scripts that i tried to execute on it , didnt worked . Does another way to solve it ?

Comment: When you write "did'nt work", it does not describe anything. Others cannot see your code, or what commands you ran, or what result you got, or how you learn, or whether you did the correct things in the right sequence.